# PHP Array Group by one field and Sum up two fields

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This are my array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [date] => 28-10-2012 [total] => 100 [earn] => 10 ) 
[1] => Array ( [date] => 28-12-2012 [total] => 100 [earn] => 10 ) 
[2] => Array ( [date] => 28-12-2012 [total] => 90 [earn] => 9 ) 
[3] => Array ( [date] => 28-12-2012 [total] => 315.35 [earn] => 31.535 ) 
[4] => Array ( [date] => 02-01-2013 [total] => 1500 [earn] => 150 ) 
[5] => Array ( [date] => 02-01-2013 [total] => 1000 [earn] => 100 ) 
)
```

Desire Output:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [date] => 28-10-2012 [total] => 100 [earn] => 10 ) 
 [1] => Array ( [date] => 28-12-2012 [total] => 505.35 [earn] => 505.535 ) 
 [2] => Array ( [date] => 02-01-2013 [total] => 2500 [earn] => 250 )  
)
```

The method I tried so far manage to group by date and sum up only one field with two different array.

```
Array ( [28-10-2012] => 100 [28-12-2012] => 505.535 [02-01-2013] => 2500)

Array ( [28-10-2012] => 10 [28-12-2012] => 50.535 [02-01-2013] => 250 )
```

Which are very different from what I am looking for, still cracking my head.
What are the possible method??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a builtin function for that, you have to write the algorithm yourself. Something like this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $row)
{
  $result[$row['date']]['date'] = $row['date'];
  $result[$row['date']]['total'] += $row['total'];
  $result[$row['date']]['earn'] += $row['earn'];
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to sum up fields in your arrays.

It's essentially the same idea as the previous answer but you should check the existence of the key otherwise you'll get an 'undefined index' on the first visit of each unique date.

While iterating, check if the row's date has been encountered before -- if so, the key will be found in the result array.

If the first encounter, push the whole row into the date-specific group in the result array.

If not the first encounter of the date, the increase the cached value in each respective column by the amount in the row's columns.

```
$arr = array(
    array( 'date'=>'28-10-2012', 'total'=>100, 'earn'=>10 ),
    array( 'date'=>'28-10-2012', 'total'=>100, 'earn'=>12 ),
    array( 'date'=>'28-11-2012', 'total'=>120, 'earn'=>12 ),
);

$newData = array();
foreach($arr as $row) {
    if(array_key_exists( $row['date'], $newData)) {
        $newData[$row['date']]['total'] += $row['total'];
        $newData[$row['date']]['earn'] += $row['earn'];         
            } else {
        $newData[$row['date']] = $row;
    }
}
```

If you wish to remove the temporary grouping keys, call `array_values()` on `$newData` after the loop.